# Calling database accessing method from within another db accessing method

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Should I avoid calling database accessing methods from within other database accessing methods (ie: having multiple `Connection`s open simultaneously)?

Say I have an `Object` `Message` and its corresponding method to retrieve it from the DB `selectMessge()`.

Say `Message` has a field called `user` which holds a `User` `Object`.
I usually code `selectMessage` to look something like this (where `rs` is the `ResultSet` `Object`):

```
...
int userId = rs.getInt("UserId");
message.setUser(User.selectUser(userId));
...
```

(`selectUser` is a database accessing method and the above obviously takes place while a `Connection` is opened)

Is the above ok? Or should I:

1. Retrieve Id
2. Close the connection
3. Retrieve the User Object (by opening and closing another `Connection`)

The latter requires more lines of code since I would need a separate field in the `Message` `Object` for the user's Id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your requirement. Making another connection during one open should not be a problem unless you run out of connections. 
Although if you are using JPA or hibernate, it will have a different mechanism of handling queries, so you may not end up in such situation at all.

IMHO this is perfectly Ok, as long as you have your database supporting enough connections. Many cases such things are done.

But from code and performance  point of view, I see you will have some other issues.

1. As I see the database handling and business handling is not isolated, this may result in tight coupling which in turn can cause increased maintenance cost.
2. As I see you are making query after reading userId from the resultset. So either you are processing a batch, or you are processing single record. If it is a batch, you can very well collect all user Ids and fetch the records later. This will have significant performance impact, and if you have a single record, then the best is to use a JOIN query, this will also save you one database trip, which is important as well.